# A trigonometric inequality involving sine

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, inequality

Let $0<a<\pi/2,0<b<\pi/2$, $0<\lambda<1, \mu=1-\lambda$. Does anyone see a good proof
of the inequality:

$$\sin(\lambda a)\sin(\lambda b)+\sin(\lambda a)\sin(\mu b)\cos(b)+\sin(\lambda b)\sin(\mu a)\cos(a)+\sin(\mu a)\sin(\mu b)>\sin(a)\sin(b).$$

Comment: The LHS equals the RHS for $a=b=\pi/4,\lambda=\mu=1/2$.